# Where are the best explanations of variables, pointers, references and memory addresses on the net?

Tags: c++, c, objective-c, pointers

Although I think that I've got that now (the light bulb is pretty bright now but still flickering a little bit), I'd like to read more stuff about pointers, variables, references, memory addresses, etc. Just the whole thing, i.e. what I have to understand when hearing thre term "reference" (think it's just a pointer, not sure).

So let us know your sources! Great articles, books, PDF's, videos, whatever. Anything is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I would have sworn this was a duplicate, but I can't find it. Good question.

Answer (score 5):

[Pointers, References, and Arrays in C++](http://www.gnomesane.net/code/doc/ptrarray/) has a wonderful explanation of the basics.

Answer (score 2):

Help yourself with a book. A good one is ["The Objective-C Programming Language"](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/ObjC.pdf) from Apple.  It is well written and free:

Also, see:

- "Programming in Objective-C" by Stephen Kochan
- "Learning Cocoa with Objective-C" by James Duncan

As for C and C++ resources: these have been discussed before on SO -- try searching the site.

- [Objective C Resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571/cocoa-and-objective-c-resources)
- [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)
- [The Definitive C Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Answer (score 2):

What I found the most confusing is the difference between an array and a pointer in C. Here's the [C FAQ](http://www.it.usyd.edu.au/~dasymond/mirror/c-faq/aryptr/aryptrequiv.html) which finally explained that to me.

Read here the [whole FAQ](http://www.it.usyd.edu.au/~dasymond/mirror/c-faq/aryptr/index.html) about pointers and arrays.

Answer (score 2):

i always liked this one:

http://cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/

and of course this faq

http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/

Answer (score 2):

about pointer:

> Pointers on C by Kenneth
>   Reek

Comment: that book isn't specifically about pointers, but is about the C language. The title is a pun. However, it is a great book :-).

Comment: I was going to recommend this book if only for the fact that the author used to be an integral member of my schools CS department. I often use header files with his name on them. ;)

Comment: "used to be an integral member of my schools CS department."  It must really suck to have CS departments with fractional members ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm studying engineering and we had this little crash course in C and went through this book called "How to program C" by Deitel. It covers all the basics and has a few code samples in it.

However; Pointers can be tricky to get, especially from only reading about them. I strongly recommend [this lecture by Richard Buckland about pointers](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rxvv9krECNw).

Then of course, just start experimenting. It is the best way to learn this subject.

Answer (score 1):

This has to be the most articulate & awesome pointer tutorial & reference i have ever come across.

http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/

It does not assume any pre-requisites & it slowly builds from the basics to most advanced topics & has lots of code & sample problems too.

Thanks Nick Parlante for this awesome resource.

Lots of other useful resources are available at
http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~nick/